# Using keyboard input to trigger WebDriver events using Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, keyboard-events

Im trying to accelerate the use of a web application using selenium Webdriver by creating hotkeys for it. I want certain webdriver click events to be associated with keyboard keys. For example, pressing "s" on the keyboard will click on the submit button.

I understand how to do the clicking and locating elements with webdriver but don't know how to go about listening to the keys from Java while Firefox is open (from a webdriver get call). My application has no GUI and since it's opening a firefox window it will lose focus so KeyListener is not an option.

I have come accross the JNI library that I'm looking into. Any other suggestions how I may do this?

Comment: My honest opinion is to ask your developers to implement such key shortcuts directly to the page. Or else you will spend days developing something like java application with integrated web browser which is listening to key events...

Comment: Hi Pavel, it is not my application but I need to use it daily and takes a lot of time to manually perform the repetitive tasks, that's why I'd like to create hotkeys for my personal use. I agree asking for the hotkeys to be added would be ideal if it were my app. When I say my application has no GUI, etc Im referring to the Java/WebDriver application Im developing that operates on the web application that is already there

Comment: Have come accross this library that may do the trick: http://kra.lc/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/

Comment: I used the java-global-system-hook for the keyboard from the link above and it's working. Has anyone used the .jar before and can verify it's not malicious code? It's derived from the JNI original library.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, it is *almost always* better idea to automate the **whole process**

Say, you need to daily update salary of the employees. It is better idea to invest your time to read XLS file (almost standard way how those data are delivered to the people destined to do the repetitive work) and read line by line and somehow enter it to the application.

I know I did not provide you the answer you were expecting, but try to think of automating the whole process. It might be little tricky, but doable - and at the end faster - than simple mapping of the keys

Comment: Hi again Pavel, thanks for the answer. I am familiar with the JXL library and in case of getting data as an XLS file, automating the whole process is the way to go. In this case I cannot automate the whole process, as I need to verify data manually, but once the data is verified, inputting it into the web application can be automated - that is where the hotkeys would be useful.

Comment: well, how do you verify data? And while verifying, you can for example create new file with verified data. ;)

Comment: I was thinking of something like if data is good press key A and it's saved in file X, if the data needs rechecking later, press B and it's emailed to person Y, etc. The verification is manual and I need the best way to hook to the OS to read the keys since I dont think it's possible from Java alone. For now I'm using the .jar linked to above and it's working ok - but maybe there's a simpler solution to this.